# How to override WooCommerce shortcode's output?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a Wordpress theme, where I want to change the generated markup of the `[product_category]` WooCommerce shortcode. I browsed through the templates directory in the plugin, but can't find the file related to this particular shortcode.

So my question is, which files I have to copy to my template and modify to change the HTML outcome of `[product_category]`? (CSS modifications are already done, but I need to display a very different HTML markup, and I don't want to hack around with JS).

Also it would be better not to rewrite the whole function with a hook, but change the original HTML a bit (for example, set the background color based on a custom meta field).

Comment: The only way to get a different html markup without using javascript/jQuery is to build your own shortcode based on classes [`WC_Shortcodes`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Shortcodes.html) and [`WC_Shortcode_Products`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Shortcode_Products.html)

Comment: That's an ok solution, I already have my own shortcode (which is only a wrapper for product_category), but I don't know where can I look up the default product_category shortcode, to get a clue on how to implement it with different markup.

Comment: The `[product_category]` call the single product template… so it depends if you want to alter the html structure on the product themselves… If it's the case you should need to call a customized template instead.

Answer (score -1):

**Esiest way :)**

```
add_shortcode('test','test_show_shortcode');
function test_show_shortcode( $atts ) {
    echo do_shortcode('[products limit="100" columns="..." category="..."]');

}
```

**[test]**